# Solving $\binom{39}{5+2x}=\binom{39}{2x-2}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I have this equation: $$\binom{39}{5+2x}=\binom{39}{2x-2}$$

And I don't know how to solve it. I've tried by the definition of combination but I get stuck.

I get stuck here:[image]

Comment: The definition is a good start. Can you show where you get stuck?

Comment: If one would use the symmetric property in the answers below, one would need to show that it would yield all solutions. That is maybe a suitable exercise to do afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$$\binom np=\binom nq\iff p+q=n \text{ OR } p=q$$

Answer (score 0):

we have

$\binom{n}{p}=\binom{n}{n-p}$

so your equation offers two possibilities:

$5+2x=2x-2$ which is not possible

or

$5+2x=39-(2x-2) $  which gives

$x=\frac{36}{4}=9$.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve  this question  very easily by using the property
$\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{n-r} $

Change the term on the RHS to$$ \binom{39}{41-2x} $$
Now equate the bases of both combinations and you'll get 
$$5+ 2x = 41-2x $$
Solving for x you'll get $$x = 9 $$

Answer (score 0):

Think about $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$.

Then

$39-(5+2x)=2x-2$

$39-5-2x=2x-2$

$34-2x=2x-2$

$4x=36$

$x=9$

Alternatively you could have set it up also as

$5+2x=39-(2x-2)$

and solved for $x$ as well.